# 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1265U dell 7430 issue with graphic card or monitor after ubuntu update

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, bug-reporting

My Dell latitude 7430 laptop with 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1265U (Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)) seems to have a strange issue with graphic card or monitor after ubuntu update.

My external monitors function perfectly fine, but the mouse on the laptop screen lags and blackouts part of the screen as it moves. Photos of the behavior is attached.

When I disconnect the external monitors, the behavior persist on the laptop, i.e. I cannot use it. In other words, without the external monitors, the laptop is unusable.

In the past, I did not have this issue, but on the laptop only, sometimes the touchpad would lock and after logging in the issue would solve. This behavior did not show with external mouse.

When I tested with windows, I did not observe this behavior.
The same applies to Boot Ubuntu loaded from bootable flash drive.
So I think the issue is related to the latest ubuntu update (5.19.0-32-generic). I do not know how to investigate this issue further.

[image: photo of the issue 1]
[image]

Here is the list of the latest installed updates. Any idea?

```
 2023-02-22 09:56:27 install libv4l2rds0:amd64 <none> 1.22.1-2build1
 2023-02-22 09:56:28 install v4l-utils:amd64 <none> 1.22.1-2build1
 2023-02-22 09:57:03 install libportaudio2:amd64 <none> 19.6.0-1.1
 2023-02-22 09:57:03 install libguvcview-2.0-2:amd64 <none> 2.0.7-2-1
 2023-02-22 09:57:04 install guvcview:amd64 <none> 2.0.7-2-1
 2023-02-22 09:57:04 install libwebcam0:amd64 <none> 0.2.4-1.1ubuntu2
 2023-02-22 09:57:04 install uvcdynctrl-data:all <none> 0.2.4-1.1ubuntu2
 2023-02-22 09:57:04 install uvcdynctrl:amd64 <none> 0.2.4-1.1ubuntu2
 2023-02-22 18:25:17 install srvadmin-hapi:amd64 <none> 9.5.0
 2023-02-22 18:25:29 install command-configure:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-595
```

Below, see earlier update logs:

```
2023-02-13 16:11:47 install libegl1-mesa:amd64 <none> 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1
2023-02-13 16:11:47 install libxcb-xtest0:amd64 <none> 1.14-3ubuntu3
2023-02-13 16:11:47 install zoom:amd64 5.12.2.4816 5.13.7.683
2023-02-14 09:49:07 install libb2-1:amd64 <none> 0.98.1-1.1
2023-02-14 09:49:07 install libfdk-aac2:amd64 <none> 2.0.2-1
2023-02-14 09:49:08 install libluajit-5.1-common:all <none> 2.1.0~beta3+dfsg-6
2023-02-14 09:49:08 install libluajit-5.1-2:amd64 <none> 2.1.0~beta3+dfsg-6
2023-02-14 09:49:08 install libqt6core6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4+dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
2023-02-14 09:49:08 install libqt6dbus6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4+dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
2023-02-14 09:49:08 install libqt6gui6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4+dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
2023-02-14 09:49:08 install libqt6network6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4+dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
2023-02-14 09:49:09 install libqt6opengl6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4+dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
2023-02-14 09:49:09 install libqt6qml6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4+dfsg-3ubuntu1
2023-02-14 09:49:09 install libqt6qmlmodels6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4+dfsg-3ubuntu1
2023-02-14 09:49:09 install libqt6quick6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4+dfsg-3ubuntu1
2023-02-14 09:49:09 install libqt6svg6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4-1ubuntu1
2023-02-14 09:49:09 install libqt6waylandclient6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4-1
2023-02-14 09:49:09 install libqt6waylandcompositor6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4-1
2023-02-14 09:49:10 install libqt6waylandeglclienthwintegration6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4-1
2023-02-14 09:49:10 install libqt6waylandeglcompositorhwintegration6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4-1
2023-02-14 09:49:10 install libqt6widgets6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4+dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
2023-02-14 09:49:10 install libqt6wlshellintegration6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4-1
2023-02-14 09:49:10 install libqt6xml6:amd64 <none> 6.2.4+dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
2023-02-14 09:49:10 install libts0:amd64 <none> 1.22-1
2023-02-14 09:49:11 install qt6-wayland:amd64 <none> 6.2.4-1
2023-02-14 09:49:11 install qt6-qpa-plugins:amd64 <none> 6.2.4+dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
2023-02-14 09:49:11 install obs-studio:amd64 <none> 29.0.2-0obsproject1~jammy
2023-02-14 09:49:13 install qt6-gtk-platformtheme:amd64 <none> 6.2.4+dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
2023-02-14 10:20:18 install gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0:amd64 <none> 1.20.3-0ubuntu1
2023-02-14 10:20:18 install gnome-sound-recorder:all <none> 42.0-1
2023-02-14 10:23:04 install audio-recorder:amd64 <none> 3.3.4~jammy
```

```
libdrm-radeon1/jammy-updates,now 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-radeon/jammy-updates,now 1:19.1.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

p.s. loading previous ubuntu version (5.17) does not help either. I tested switching gnome & xorg, but the problem persists.

Comment: You can boot with a previous kernel using grub menu and see what is there.

Comment: The graphic card ia intel. The update was on auto update lst. Tried loading 5.17, didn't help.

Comment: I noticed that after installing these packages, I observed this behavior. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem, it seems to be related to Dell laptops as it doesn't occur for my Lenovo laptop.
For me what helped (short term) was to revert back to an earlier kernel; it seems to work fine using 5.15.0-43-generic for now. Later kernel updates seem to have the same issue: trying to upgrade to version 6.2 didn't change the problem and running the newest fedora distribution on a bootable usb caused the same problem.

Comment: I wonder how can we communicate this issue to Ubuntu as a bug of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

After tons of updating and software testing, this issue was a hardware issue. Today, the dell technician replaced the motherboard and screen, and the problem was fixed without doing anything on the operating system-side.

Just in case anyone faces the same issue in the future.